# 2 viewmodels working on the same ObservableCollection, 1 viewmodel not updating

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have 2 viewmodels that inherit from the same BaseViewModel, which has an ObservableCollection as a public property.
The first viewmodel shows the ObservableCollection, while the second viewmodel allows for updating the collection.

How come the first view doesn't see the updated collection?

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Playlist _currentPlaylist;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    public Playlist CurrentPlaylist
    {
        get
        {
            if (_currentPlaylist == null)
            {
                _currentPlaylist = _library.CurrentPlaylist;
            }
            return _currentPlaylist;
        }
        set
        {
            _currentPlaylist = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentPlaylist");
        }
    }

    public BaseViewModel()
    {
        _library = new Library();
        _dbContext = new MusicTrackerDataContext();
    }
}
```

The first view that uses the inherited BaseViewModel uses `CurrentPlaylist` databound.
The second view sets the `CurrentPlaylist` again:

```
public class ArtistPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

    public void PlaylistBtn_Clicked(ListView albumListView)
    {
        Library.AddSelectionToCurrentPlaylist(albumListView.SelectedItems.Cast<Album>());
        CurrentPlaylist = Library.CurrentPlaylist;
    }
}
```

Seeing that my `BaseViewModel` raises the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event when I set my `CurrentPlaylist`, I'd expect that the listview to which my `CurrentPlaylist` is bound, is updated.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

The code for the View that's showing the old collection

```
public sealed partial class HubPage : Page
{
    private HubPageViewModel _hubPageViewModel;

    public HubPageViewModel HubPageViewModel
    { 
        get
        {
            return _hubPageViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML code for my `HubPageViewModel`

```
<Page
x:Class="MyProject.HubPage"
DataContext="{Binding HubPageViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<HubSection x:Uid="HubSection5" Header="Now Playing"
            DataContext="{Binding CurrentPlaylist}" HeaderTemplate="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderTemplate}">
    <DataTemplate>
        <ListView 
            SelectionMode="None"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Tracks}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
        </HubSection>
```

**Edit 2**

I've changed my code to the following (according to the comments)

```
public sealed partial class HubPage : Page
{
    private readonly NavigationHelper navigationHelper;
    private static HubPageViewModel _hubPageViewModel; // Made it static

    public HubPageViewModel HubPageViewModel
    { 
        get
        {
            return _hubPageViewModel;
        }
    }
}

<Page
x:Class="MyProject.HubPage"
DataContext="{Binding HubPageViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
xmlns:vm="using:MyProject.ViewModels" // Added reference to my VM
mc:Ignorable="d">
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <vm:HubPageViewModel x:Name="hubPageViewModel"/> // Added the key
    </ResourceDictionary>
        <HubSection x:Uid="HubSection5" Header="Now Playing"
                    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource hubPageViewModel}}" HeaderTemplate="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderTemplate}">
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListView 
                    SelectionMode="None"
                    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentPlaylist.Tracks}"
                    ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,27.5" Holding="StackPanel_Holding">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
```

But it's still not updated when I return from my second viewmodel.

Comment: How are you binding the viewmodel to the view?

Comment: @user1522548 I've added the relevant code.

Comment: Ok that's the problem.  You can't bind like that (or at least I've not been sucessful doing that in the past except a long time ago before MSFT changed the DTE binding tools)...  Try this instead, set up a static reference to your view model in the view. You'll need to reference the namespace and then in the Page.Resources find it.  From there you can then use the properties page in VS to find the collection to bind.  This is the best way to do it because there's never any reason why it won't work.  If the designer can see the property so can the runtime.

Comment: You can also possibly get a better glimpse of this problem by watching the output window when you start the application, you should see some binding errors.

Comment: Yes I did say ViewModel.... you don't want this code in the code behind of the view anyway.  Just create a new class called VMHubPage put all the code there.

Comment: @user1522548 Could you explain your solution a bit more, perhaps in an answer? I'm a bit new to WP dev.

Comment: @user1522548 Could you explain a bit further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though both view models inherit the same base class, the state of the base class is not shared between the two view models. That is, `HubPageViewModel` and `ArtistPageViewModel` do not share the same instance of Playlist. They are completely different properties.

Since both view models points to the same playlist instance and that instance is an `ObservableCollection`, all changes to that instance of `ObservableCollection` will be shared between the two view models because both views are bound to the "collection changed" notifications for the instance they are watching. In your example, `ArtistPageViewModel.PlaylistBtn_Clicked` does not changes the data within the `ObservableCollection`, it changes the collection itself. This changes the collection that the second view is watching but does not change the one of the first view.

Comment: So I should update my instance of `CurrentPlaylist` and push those changes through to my model? Why doesn't it register that I set my collection? Doesn't my `NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentPlaylist");` take care of that?

Comment: Your answer solved my problem. Once the wait period is over I'll give you the points. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem! As for your other questions: 1/ yes, you could update the existing playlist instead, but if you still need to completely replace it, you need to bind your playlist between your view models instead of sharing it through a base view model. 2/ the notification is not global for all instances of BaseViewModel and their children. It is only valid for this instance that sent the notification. In your case, you have an instance of HubPageViewModel and ArtistPageViewModel, initially sharing the same playlist, but both with their own notifications and own reference to the playlist.